# duda sobre phpmayler(como enviar varios correos tomando el email desde una bd)

Tags: php

Hola tengo la siguiente duda o problema,verán tengo una bd llamada **usuarios** y una tabla llamada **datos**, lo que quiero es que los registros de dicha tabla o para ser mas específico, el campo donde la dirección de correo es almacenada sea usada por *phpmayler* para los envíos,básicamente quiero que todos los email de mi **db** reciban un correo. También que cada uno de ellos reciba un archivo adjunto ya sea una imagen o `txt`. Comenté algunas secciones del código debido a que son las pruebas que he hecho la cuales no han dado resultado

Estoy usando la ultima versión de **phpmayler** y `xampp`,también `PHP 7`.

```html
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'require/Exception.php';
require 'require/PHPMailer.php';
require 'require/SMTP.php';



$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 
    $mail->isSMTP();                                           
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';           
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                  
    $mail->Username   = '***';                   
    $mail->Password   = '1234;                          
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('*****', '***');
    $mail->addAddress('****','***'); 

    //send much user
    /*foreach($_POST['opcion'] as $email) {
      $mail->addAddress($mail);
      //o bcc
      $mail->addBcc($mail);
} */

    // Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('Exception.php');       
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');
 

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = 'Prueba';
    $mail->Body    = ':v<b>Prueba!</b>';
 

    $mail->send();
    echo 'enviado';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```